# For loop in makefile not working

Tags: bash, makefile, gnu-make

In my makefile I have:

```
all:
  for i in {20..50000..10} ; do \
    echo "Computing $$i" ;\
  done
```

Which should print numbers 20, 30, 40, ..., 50000 each on a separate line.

This works under Debian oldstable (GNU Make 4.0, GNU Bash 4.3), but not Debian stable (GNU Make 4.1 and GNU Bash 4.4.12).

Debian stable prints just the string "{20..50000..10}". Why is this? What is the portable way to write this for loop in a makefile?

Comment: For me it worked after I replaced `$$i` with `$i`. Could you try that?

Comment: @dmadic This does not work for me. My software prints nothing (it probably treats `$i` as a makefile variable and prints empty string).

Comment: Why don't you use `seq`? `seq 20 10 50000`

Comment: `seq` is no more standard than the braces, so it's adding one more external dependency that isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: The braces is a bashism so you should install bash - one more external dependency :) See MadScientist's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50144927/934599)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Stick with a POSIX-compatible loop:

```
all:
  i=20; while [ "$$i" -le 50000 ]; do \
    echo "Computing $$i"; i=$$((i + 10));\
  done
```

Comment: In my case it works with the loop condition `[ "$$i" -le 5000 ];`. Moreover with the colon `:` it does an infinite loop with `$i = 20` all the time. Without the colon it works flawlessly. Are these typos or should I be worried for portability?

Comment: Yes, just typos. I'm not used to writing extended shell in a Makefile, so forgot the double `$$`. Originally, I used assignment with the arithmetic expression (`$(( i = i + 10))`) before deciding that was unnecessarily complicated, but forgot to remove the `:` to turn it into a regular shell assignment.

Answer (score 6):

If you run this at your shell prompt:

```
/bin/sh -c 'for i in {20..5000..10}; do echo $i; done'
```

you'll see it doesn't work as you'd hoped.  Make always invokes `/bin/sh` (which should be a POSIX shell) to run recipes: it would be a disaster for portability if it used whatever shell the person invoking the makefile happened to be using.

If you really want to write your makefile recipes in bash syntax, then you have to ask for that explicitly by adding:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```

to your makefile.